# flexbox justify-content multiple tags underneath eachother

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a `div` with a `h1` and `h2` tag in it, my goal is to center them horizontally and vertically I am using flexbox but this is how my code acts

```
 --------------
|              |
|     h1h2     |
|              |
 --------------
```

my goal is this

```
 --------------
|              |
|     h1       |
|     h2       |
|              |
 --------------
```

my html:

```
<div class="announcement">
    <h1>h1</h1>
    <h2>h2</h2>
</div>
```

my css:

```
.announcement {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

I've tried doing a `<br>` after the `<h1>` but doesnt do anyhting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `flex-direction: column;`. As by default, the flex layout is direction is `row`

```
.announcement {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!

Comment: @MikloVuba Welcome, Please accept the answer also.